# Display a message

Tags: acumatica

What' the quickest way to display a message similar to *MsgBox* in C# ?
I've tried this:

```
Base.Document.View.Ask("Hello World", MessageButtons.OK);
```

It publishes but I'm getting an error when it executes.

Comment: Take a habit of always providing errors you get when asking questions

Comment: what is the error and where are you calling that line of code? What event or button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that use case, throwing an exception will be enough:

```
throw new PXException("Hello World");
```

It uses the browser themed message box:
[image]

For debugging I prefer using traces:

```
PXTrace.WriteInformation("Hello World");
```

Message will appear in the trace window:
[image]

You can open the trace window in the help menu from most Acumatica screens:
[image]

Comment: I was using the PXException before on simple actions or menu. But then when I used it on events, obviously the whole method just collapses. So I was wondering if there's a MsgBox equivalent. Thanks for the PXTrace, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Regarding the 'Ask' method, can you try Base.Document.Ask instead of Base.Document.View.Ask. Having the error message, which should be shown in the trace window would help to identify your problem.

Comment: Tried Base.Document.Ask. It compiles but there's an error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UIO3.png) when it executes

Comment: Ask uses exception mechanism for communication. I suspect at the time Ask is called the framework is not ready to catch the exception. This could happen for example if Ask is called in a constructor. Have you tried putting it in an Action event handler, for example in response to user click on a button? That's the kind of scenario Ask was designed for.